# jQuery Javascript Group Years by Decades

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have the below which loops through each div and returns the year that each div represents, but what I'd like to do is group the returned years into arrays of the decades. I'm not quite sure how to do that and was hoping someone could help with this.

```
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1994">This is 1994<div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1997">This is 1997<div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2001">This is 2001<div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2003">This is 2003<div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2012">This is 2012<div>


$('.timeline-events').each(function(){
    console.log(this.className.match(/timeline-year-(\d+)?/)[1]);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv51tu9z/)

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: If I could get it into an array per decade or as json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work out the decade of a year by dividing by ten, flooring it and multiplying the result.

From there on out it's grouping by your decade and merging it into your object:

```
var groupedByDecade = {};
$('.timeline-events').each(function(){
    var year = this.className.match(/timeline-year-(\d+)?/)[1],
        decade = Math.floor(year/10)*10;
    groupedByDecade[decade] = $.merge(groupedByDecade[decade] || [], [year]);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mv51tu9z/4/)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED for grouping using underscore.

http://jsfiddle.net/9o39jxLo/1/

```
var data = []; 
var decadedata = new Array();
$(function() {
$('.timeline-events').each(function(){
var year = (this.className.match(/timeline-year-(\d+)?/)[1]);

    var decade = year - (year % 10);
    data.push({ "decade": decade, "year": year});

});

});

function testdecade(){
    var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, function(d){return d.decade});
console.log(groupedData);

                    }
```

Comment: Aside from displaying the decade to console, you are not doing anything useful with it (like using it to group entries as requested).

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```js
// iterate over each of the '.timeline-events' elements:
$('.timeline-events').each(function() {
  // finding first the specific (four-digit) year,
  // then getting a substring, for the decade and adding a 0:
  var decade = (/timeline\-year\-(\d{4})/).exec(this.className)[1].substring(2, 3) + '0',
    // if the previous element to the current element is a decade-grouping element and
    // it's the appropriate decade, we use that element; otherwise we create a new one:
    decadeDiv = $(this).prev('.decade-' + decade).length ? $(this).prev('.decade-' + decade) : $('<div />', {
      'class': 'decade-' + decade
    // and insert that element before the current element:
    }).insertBefore(this);
  // we then append this element to the decade grouping element:
  $(this).appendTo(decadeDiv);
});
```

```html
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1994">This is 1994
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1997">This is 1997
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2001">This is 2001
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2003">This is 2003
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2012">This is 2012
</div>
```

In response to the clarification, in the comments to the question, that you'd like a JSON string, I'd suggest (assuming you want the HTML of the elements) the following:

```
var decadeGroups = {};
$('.timeline-events').map(function () {
    var decade = [].filter.call(this.classList, function (cName) {
        return cName.indexOf('timeline-year-') === 0;
    }).join('').match(/\d{2}$/)[0].replace(/\d$/, '0');
    if (decadeGroups[decade]) {
        decadeGroups[decade].push(this.outerHTML);
    }
    else {
        decadeGroups[decade] = [this.outerHTML];
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(decadeGroups));
```

```js
// initialising an object:
var decadeGroups = {};

// iterating over the '.timeline-events' elements:
$('.timeline-events').each(function() {
  // reducing the array-like classList,
  var decade = [].filter.call(this.classList, function(cName) {
    // keeping only the class-name that starts with 'timeline-year-':
    return cName.indexOf('timeline-year-') === 0;
    // turning that into a string with join('')
    // matching the last two digits of the year,
    // replacing the last digit with a zero:
  }).join('').match(/\d{2}$/)[0].replace(/\d$/, '0');
  // if the object has a key of the current decade:
  if (decadeGroups[decade]) {
    // we add the outerHTML of the current element to that array:
    decadeGroups[decade].push(this.outerHTML);
  } else {
    // otherwise we create a new object key, and assign an array
    // containing the outerHTML of the current element:
    decadeGroups[decade] = [this.outerHTML];
  }
});

// logging the JSON-stringified object:
console.log(JSON.stringify(decadeGroups));
```

```html
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1994">This is 1994
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-1997">This is 1997
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2001">This is 2001
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2003">This is 2003
</div>
<div class="timeline-events timeline-year-2012">This is 2012
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - `Element.classList`.
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
  - [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly;

```
var decades = {};
$('.timeline-events').each(function(){
    var year = this.className.match(/timeline-year-(\d+)?/)[1];
    var decade = year.substring(0,3) + "0";
    if (decades.hasOwnProperty( decade )) {
         decades[ decade ].push(year);
    } else {
        decades[ decade ] = [ year ];
    }

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(decades));
```

this creates an object with "decades" as property name which are of the type array, where the array contains the years.